# How to concatenate numerous column names in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I would like to concatenate all the columns with comma-delimitted in pandas.

But as you can seem it is very laborious tasks since I manually typed all the column indices.

`de = data[3]+","+data[4]+","+data[5]+....+","+data[1511]`

do you have any idea to avoid above procedure in pandas in python3?

Answer (score 1):

First convert all columns to strings by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and then possible add `join` per rows:

```
df = data.astype(str).apply(','.join, axis=1)
```

Or after convert to strings add `,`, then `sum` and last remove last `,` by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
df = data.astype(str).add(',').sum(axis=1).str.rstrip(',')
```

Comment: it throw error as below. >>> df = data.apply(','.join, axis=1)

TypeError: ('sequence item 46: expected str instance, int found', 'occurred at index 0')